# ReportViewer - how to filter on Multi Value Parameter

Tags: filter, reportviewer, multiple-value

I have a report that uses a Multi Value parameter. I have added this to the report and can specify the parameter values in code.

Now I want to filter the data on the report by the multiple value parameter. Eg, I pass in a list of account no's and I want to filter the data on the report so only records with the passed in account no's are shown.

In the tablix properties there is a filters option which looks like the place I need to set up the filters.

I have added a new one, selected the Account Number column on the report. The operator that seems relevant to me is the 'in' operator. So show records that a 'in' this list. However, If i select the 'in' filter the expression text box is disabled. Is this what im meant to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

You should filter on The name of the parameter rather than an expression.

eg:

```
[@CostCentres]
```

rather than:

```
=Parameters!CostCentres.Value
```

Comment: Note that the square brackets are mandatory. It fails otherwise.